# Objective c ERROR: incompatible types for argument 2 of 'NSRunAlertPanel'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, floating-point, nsrunalertpanel

Here is the code:

```
float charlieSoundVolume;
charlieSoundVolume = [charlieSoundLevel floatValue];

NSRunAlertPanel(@"CHARLIE",charlieSoundVolume, @"", @"", @"Ok");
```

This gives me the error:
incompatible types for argument 2 of 'NSRunAlertPanel'

Will NSRunAlertPanel not accept floats?

Any ideas??

Elijah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd be surprised that it doesn't take floats given the documentation:

```
NSInteger NSRunAlertPanel (
   NSString *title,
   NSString *msg,
   NSString *defaultButton,
   NSString *alternateButton,
   NSString *otherButton,
   ...
);
```

Pass a string.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Can you show an example? Thanks for your help and fast response!

Comment: Better yet, I can show you how to answer it yourself.   Read this document:  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html